# Gnome online accounts

Tags: gnome-terminal

I successfully installed gnome-online-accounts on my PC, equipped with Debian 9 OS. Everything works fine if I work from the X-terminal, having logged on with the default user. The command:

```
gio list google-drive://XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com/
```

gives the expected results.
But it doesn't if the same command is given thru crontab, though from the same default user. Here is the message:

```
gio: google-drive://XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com/: Operation not supported
```

If the problem was caused by an unmounted file system, due to lost of connectivity, the message should be:

```
gio: google-drive://XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com/: The specified location is not mounted
```

It seems like the command was given by another user.
Anyone has an idea about where is the trick?

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at the end of [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/ch02.html), inside the bash script executed by crontab, before the gio call, it should be added:

```
declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/XXXX/bus
```

The XXXX value must be replaced by the UID value of the user enabled to the goa connection. This value is often "1000".